# Syntax error on INSERT INTO OLEDB C#

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection

Syntax error on INSERT INTO Statement please help. im exporting data from dataGridview.im looping in each rows.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RP_CMG01 (ACCT_NO,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MID_NAME,NICK_NAME,AGE,SEX,CIVIL_STAT,SALUTATION,EDUC,EMPLOYMENT,REG_DATE,REC_STATUS,LOG)VALUES" +
                    "(" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ACCT_NO"].Value + "," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["LAST_NAME"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["FIRST_NAME"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["MID_NAME"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["NICK_NAME"].Value + "'," +
                    "" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["AGE"].Value + "," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SEX"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CIVIL_STAT"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SALUTATION"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["EDUC"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["EMPLOYMENT"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["REG_DATE"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["REC_STATUS"].Value + "'," +
                    "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["LOG"].Value + "');";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Members data record inserted successfully");
```

is it correct if im passing to and int field i should remove the single quote (')? thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use parameters instead concatenation dataGrid.Row cell values. 1. It protect you from SQL injections. 2. The exception will not be raised.

Comment: You need a space before and after VALUES

Comment: And i think the reason of exception is ' symbol in one of row cell values.

Comment: What is the datatype of each column?

Comment: @Alexander good evening sir. can u give me example on using parameters? as of now i only knew this kind of method. thank you

Comment: @BrianDriscoll which (') should i remove? about data types, acct_no and age are integers, the rest are varchar(10)(50).

Comment: I don't think you need to remove any single quotes. I think it's more likely that one of the data cell values contains a single quote that is terminating the data string. For instance, if someone's last name was "O'Malley", you would have 'O'Malley' since you are not sanitizing the data going into the database. Something like that will cause your syntax error.

Comment: @rein, use parameters someting, like this:
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
        foreach(var cell in dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells) {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + cell.Name, cell.Value); 
        }
    }

Comment: one suggestion i can give u is put a debug point near execute nonquery and when it fires copy the command text using quick watch and check it in sql server or manually you can check for syntax issues.

Comment: when there is no value in the integer also you may find the error unlike string which will have empty in the single quotes.

Comment: @Alexander sir, if you may can u show and explain whats happening if i use parameters? sorry im really new and confused. our school teaches that method im using. your method is really new to me.